# MongoDB: How to add an array containing reduced values of the most recent subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: Person and Details. Person is the main document and Details is a document with the details of a person. Every Person document contains an array of subdocument _id's (details) and every Details documents refers to Person. Details is practically that contains the daily activity of a Person. There is one Details document per Person for every single day.

What I need to do is to output the Details in three different ways:

- Details of yesterday. I need the Person document and the most recent Details document.
- Reduced details of five most recent days
- Reduced details of ten most recent days

The first thing is fairly easy. I can just sort the subdocuments by date and get the most recent one, but how can I do the last two?

I am trying to build the aggregation in MongoDB Compass and this is where I am at at the moment:

```
[
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'details', 
      'localField': 'details', 
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'details_test'
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$details_test'
    }
  }, {
    '$sort': {
      'details_test.createdAt': -1
    }
  }
]
```

This gets me all the details documents sorted by date, but how would I go about creating a new details document with summed values from X number of most recent documents?

Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I would need to have stats output always in the following format:

```
{
  yesterday: [Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4, Person5 ...],
  last5days: [Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4, Person5 ...],
  last10days: [Person1, Person2, Person3, Person4, Person5 ...]
}
```

The initial person objects have an array of details objects, but in the final objects I need the persons to have a property that contains the summed up values of the details arrays. For example:

**Initial person example for "last5days" array:**

```
name: "John Smith",
age: 40,
details: [
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 1,
  },
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 1,
  },
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 1,
  },
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 1,
  }
  {
    prop1: 1,
    prop2: 1,
  }
]
```

**Result person example for "last5days" array:**

```
name: "John Smith",
age: 40,
details: {
    prop1: 5,
    prop2: 5,
}
```

Comment: So do you want all three to be in the response Everytime? With yesterday as an array,five days as an array and ten days as an array in the same output? Please provide sample of your data and required o/p. Maybe if it's like limit operator if they're separated.

Comment: I did a small example in my opening post.